# mount system call

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am stuck at finding the correct usage of mount() system call which should be the replacment for the command

$mount -t ext3 -oloop /test /mount

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

$ strace mount -t ext3 -oloop /test /mount

And you will see that there are 2 number of system calls involved - one for setting the loopback block device and another to do the actual mount