# Linux function to get mount points

Tags: c, linux, mount, libc

Is there a function (or interface; ioctl, netlink etc) in the standard Linux libs that will return the current mounts directly from the kernel without parsing /proc?  `strace`ing the mount command, it looks like it parses files in /proc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095976/mount-system-call

Comment: @Satish that mounts a filesystem- it does not return _current mounts_

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `/proc/` ?? under linux, it is the preferred way to retrieve such information! And it is very simple too!!

Answer (score 45):

> Please see the clarification at the bottom of the answer for the reasoning being used in this answer.

Is there any reason that you would not use the `getmntent` libc library call? I do realize that it's not the same as an 'all in one' system call, but it should allow you to get the relevant information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mntent.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct mntent *ent;
  FILE *aFile;

  aFile = setmntent("/proc/mounts", "r");
  if (aFile == NULL) {
    perror("setmntent");
    exit(1);
  }
  while (NULL != (ent = getmntent(aFile))) {
    printf("%s %s\n", ent->mnt_fsname, ent->mnt_dir);
  }
  endmntent(aFile);
}
```

### Clarification

Considering that the OP clarified about trying to do this *without* having `/proc` mounted, I'm going to clarify:

> There is *no* facility outside of `/proc` for getting the fully qualified list of mounted file systems from the linux kernel. There is no system call, there is no ioctl. The `/proc` interface is the agreed upon interface.

With that said, if you don't have `/proc` mounted, you will have to parse the `/etc/mtab` file - pass in `/etc/mtab` instead of `/proc/mounts` to the initial `setmntent` call.

It is an agreed upon protocol that the `mount` and `unmount` **commands** will *maintain a list of currently mounted filesystems in the file /etc/mtab*. This is detailed in almost all [linux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)/[unix](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/1/mount)/[bsd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount&sektion=8) manual pages for these commands. So if you don't have `/proc` you can *sort of* rely on the contents of this file. It's not guaranteed to be a source of truth, but conventions are conventions for these things.

So, if you don't have `/proc`, you would use `/etc/mtab` in the `getmntent` libc library call below to get the list of file systems; otherwise you could use one of `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mountinfo` (which is recommended nowadays over `/proc/mounts`).

Comment: I have an embedded system that could have made use of this info during boot; before /proc was mounted.

Comment: Both `df` and `mount` use `/proc/self/mountinfo` instead of `/proc/mounts`, but result is the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that `getmntent` is not thread safe. There is `getmntent_r` (GNU extension).

Comment: Yes, well aware of all the limitations of the entire API cluster of *ent calls. Reading from the per process mountinfo file is now preferred.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syscall to list this information; instead, you can find it in the file `/etc/mtab`

Comment: mtab is just a symlink to /proc/mounts on most systems.

Comment: @tMC: `/proc/mounts` is an implementation detail. `/etc/mtab` is a standard file which you will find on almost any Unix-like system. I didn't check but I think it's part of the standard. So you can rely on it. And I wouldn't say "on most system". In my Ubuntu and OpenSuSE systems, it's a plain file. I do have `/proc/mounts` but it's a link :-)

Comment: I can confirm that `/etc/mtab` is not a file but a link to `/proc/mounts` on Raspbian Jessie.