# How do I get list of mounted filesystems

Tags: c, linux, api, mount

I need to parse table of mounted filesystems without using /proc/mounts since I'm parsing it to determine where proc file system is mounted. How can I do it?

I've googled it, but all answers was to use /proc

And why people are so sure that procfs is mounted to default place?

---

I'm asking out of curiosity. I understand that /proc is a standard de-facto, many tools use it and so /proc is anchored pretty good.

Linux API is consistent towards filesystem paths, all really needed information is passed via environmental variables, making possible to alter library and executable files, configuration files and so on.

I'm curios is it possible to detec `PROC_PATH` with no prior knowledge about it? I may do ftw with statvfs used as callback, but this is so ungraceful. There definetly should be more straight way.

Comment: If the procfs is not mounted to `/proc`, a lot of tools won't work any longer. You an then forget about `df`, `mount` and everything else.

Comment: can you please explain what is your exact problem? It is like asking how do I ssh in linux, if I don't run linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `df -k` ? 
google leads me to [this](http://linux.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/redhat-l/is-there-any-command-in-linux-to-list-all-mount-points-for-a-given-environment-1695279) too.

on mac you have `diskutil list`.

if you want to figure out what syscalls you need to perform in your `c` code use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find it out.

---

Another approach assuming you have access to `/` root directory used Petesh [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290177/1031417) and llolydm [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438663/1031417):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mntent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>


   void listdir(const char *name, int level)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct mntent *ent;
    FILE *aFile;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            path[len] = 0;
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            printf("%*s[%s]\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, level + 1);

        }
        else {
            printf("%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
            aFile = setmntent(entry);
            while (NULL != (ent = getmntent(aFile))) {
                 printf("%s %s\n", ent->mnt_fsname, ent->mnt_dir);
            }
            endmntent(aFile);

        }
    } while (entry = readdir(dir));
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    listdir("/", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: userspace assumes that procfs is mounted to /proc and reads all data from it is like chicken and the egg

Comment: I added a generic c code (not tested) which go through all the root directories.

Answer (score 3):

Look in /etc/mtab, it keeps track of mounted file systems.