# How to get source device of mount point in Linux programmatically?

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I want to know which device mounted on some directory, like this:

```
auto device = get_device_of_mount_point("/path/to/some/dir");
std::cout << device << std::endl; // /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Linux function to get mount points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280759/linux-function-to-get-mount-points)

Comment: I guess the first question should be how would you do it from the command line; and you can then implement that answer.  Also.  C tag is for C; C++ is for C++.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point, assuming C++17 is available:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <fstream>
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::string> get_device_of_mount_point(std::string_view path)
{
   std::ifstream mounts{"/proc/mounts"};
   std::string mountPoint;
   std::string device;

   while (mounts >> device >> mountPoint)
   {
      if (mountPoint == path)
      {
         return device;
      }
   }

   return std::nullopt;
}
```

You can use this function as follows.

```
if (const auto device = get_device_of_mount_point("/"))
   std::cout << *device << "\n";
else
   std::cout << "Not found\n";
```

Comment: Ok, it's solution. But I think the best way is parsing /proc/mount via getmntent.